# hadoop server-side logging not working

Tags: hadoop, log4j, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

Am using apache hadoop 2.6.0. When I wanted to see the stderr from job history, I'm always getting

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I tried these things:

1. from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25772041/3209177 , I added both hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar and container-log4j.properties in yarn classpath, got same result
2. Since the warn is no appender for org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server, I added `log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server = INFO` in both log4j.properties and container-log4j.properties. still no wonder.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig ?